# Difference between new Class() and ReflectionClass::newInstance()?

Tags: php

I was watching a [tutorial](http://www.lynda.com/PHP-tutorials/Preparing-basic-email/452748/472910-4.html) that deals with class and objects, and I came across this line of code that was confusing.

Is there a difference between `Class::newInstance()` and `new Class()`?

I read the documentation, and it did not appear to mention anything different so I assumed it's the same?

Comment: One difference is the exceptions thrown

Comment: @MarkBaker so both ways can be used to call a class, but just the exceptions different?

Comment: You can also use `ReflectionClass::newInstance()` to `clone` an existing instance (with all it's property values at the point of call, bypassing the constructor) if you created the ReflectionClass using an instance rather than simply a class name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `new Class()` statement created a new object instance of class named `Class`.

The `Class::newInstance()` calls a `static` method on class named `Class`. Which in your tutorial most likely will call and return `new Class()`.
The static function `newInstance` needs to be present in the class. It is not native to all php objects afaik.

This should make it clear:

```
class Foo
{
    private $bar = null;

    public static function newInstance($args){
        return new self($args);
    }

    public function __construct($bar = "nothing")
    {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }

    public function foo()
    {
        echo "Foo says:" . $this->bar . "\n";
    }
}

//create using normal new Classname Syntax
$foo1 = new Foo("me");
$foo1->foo();

//create using ReflectionClass::newInstance
$rf   = new ReflectionClass('Foo');
$foo2 = $rf->newInstance();
$foo2->foo();

//create using reflection and arguments
$foo3= $rf->newInstanceArgs(["happy"]);
$foo3->foo();

//create using static function 
$foo4 = Foo::newInstance("static");
$foo4->foo();
```

Will output:

```
Foo says:me
Foo says:nothing
Foo says:happy
Foo says:static
```

Comment: For `Class::newInstance`, so there's a method named `Class`?

Comment: now, I do understand that you need to declare `newInstance`, but can it be other name or it has to be declared as `newInstance`? So they are just different ways of calling a class? Why would one not just use the simplest way?

Comment: You could name the function as you like. `newMyInstance` or something else. And it mainly depends on the use case. Every possability has it's advantages. E.g. if you don't know the exact number of arguments, you could use a option 3 ($foo3) and pass in an array. You should read about Creational patterns if you want to learn more about this topic.

Comment: Thanks for all the help!